# Execute function once while loop the other in a Class-- Python

Tags: python

I have the following code. I want the "Initiate_sequence()" funciton only execute once, while the Analysis module looping over and over.

Also , because it will have multi assets, so the code needs to be initiate and loop multiple times.

```
import time
class Stock:

    def __init__(self,  Asset):
        self.Asset = Asset
        self.i_init = 0
        self.i_Ana = 0


    def Initiate_sequence(self):
        """One Execute Once"""

        self.i_init +=1
        print("Initiate Program")

    def Analysis(self):
        """Need to Execute every 10 Seconds"""

        self.Initiate_sequence()
        self.i_Ana += 1

        print(self.Asset)
        print(f"Init {self.i_init}")
        print(f"Ana {self.i_Ana}")

test_1 = Stock("Stock One")
test_2 = Stock("Stock Two")

while True:
    test_1.Analysis()
    test_2.Analysis()
    time.sleep(10)
```

---

So the result is like

```
Initiate Program
Stock One
Init 1
Ana 1
Initiate Program
Stock Two
Init 1
Ana 1

-----(Loop 2)----

Initiate Program
Stock One
Init 2
Ana 2
Initiate Program
Stock Two
Init 2
Ana 2
```

---

I want it to be:

```
Initiate Program #--- here only once, and not repeating 
Stock One
Init 1 #-----here the number in the Initiate_sequence() function does not change
Ana 1 #---This number will keep increasing each loop

Stock Two
Init 1 #-----here the number in the Initiate_sequence() function does not change
Ana 1 #---This number will keep increasing each loop

-----(Loop 2)----

Stock One
Init 1 #-----here the number in the Initiate_sequence() function does not change
Ana 2 #---This number will keep increasing each loop

Stock Two
Init 1 #-----here the number in the Initiate_sequence() function does not change
Ana 2 #---This number will keep increasing each loop
```

....and looping

Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
test_1.Initiate_sequence()
while True:
    test_1.Analysis()
    test_2.Analysis()
    time.sleep(10)
```

You dont even need to have a function for this. You could just straight up print 'Initiate'

Comment: Its a simplified version, my code is too much to put it here. But thanks, let me try

Comment: figured out with your help! Thank you